# Is it safe to loop over the same List simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I have a list

```
testList= new ArrayList<String>(); // gets initialized once at the very beginning init(). This list never changes. It's static and final.
```

I have a static method that checks if an input value is in this List :

```
public static boolean isInList (String var1)
            throws InterruptedException  {

        boolean in = false;

        for (String s : testList) {

            if (s.equals(var1))
            {
                in = true;
                break;
            }
        } 

        return in;
    }
```

I have a lot of threads that use this method concurrently and check if a certain value is in this list. It seems to work fine. However, I'm not sure if this is safe. Am I doing this correctly? Is it thread safe?

Comment: Yes, it is unless you're adding/deleting/updating elements on the list. By the way, use another datastructure for such queries. For example a hashmap

Comment: Why aren't you using `testList.contains(var1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can guarantee that no one is writing to the list, it's safe.

Note that even if the list is `static` and `final`, the code *itself* doesn't guarantee that the list is never modified. I recommend using `Collections.unmodifiableList()` instead, because it guarantees that no element is ever added to or removed from the list.

---

By the way, you can rewrite your code to this:

```
public static boolean isInList(String var1) {
    for (String s : testList) {
        if (Objects.equals(s, var1)) {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

or just

```
testList.contains(var1);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is thread-safe as long as no thread is modifying the list while other threads are reading it.

If you are using iterators over the list, they will "fail-fast" (as in throw `ConcurrentModificationException`) if the list is modified under them.  Other methods of accessing (i.e. `get(n)`) won't throw an exception but may return unexpected results.

This is all covered in great detail in the Javadoc for `List` and `ArrayList`, which you should study carefully.

Comment: And, just to note, the list must have been safely published to each of the threads in the first place. *Most* methods of handling references to threads will be fine; just don't store it in a non-volatile static field and have the threads read from that. Also of note, for a non-threadsafe list (like ArrayList), you can't rely on the fail-fast behavior of ConcurrentModificationException, since the very values it relies on for the check are prone to race conditions.

Comment: The list's iterator method (which is called in your for loop) returns a new instance of the iterator, each time it is called, so you can loop through the list many times simultaneously without problem

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is not a thread safe object. It may works for you now, but in general, when working with threads, you should make sure you're using thread-safe objects that will work with your threads as you expect.

You can use [Collections.synchronizedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))

`testList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());`